# QGraphicsItem setPos() not triggered

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

And again, trying to implement bezier curves redactor. There is

```
class BezierNode : public QGraphicsItem

BezierNode::BezierNode(QPointF point, Type type) : QGraphicsItem()
{
    setPos(point);
    setFlags(ItemIsMovable | ItemSendsScenePositionChanges | ItemSendsGeometryChanges);
}
```

It properly moves around in scene on mousePress + mouseMove, and I can catch events in  `itemChange()` for some additional acting with control points. In `QGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent()` (according to Qt source on [gitorious](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/7d70583589aee971c7adf101edc8bb4b6f0066aa:src/gui/graphicsview/qgraphicsitem.cpp#L7142)) there is a call to `item->setPos(...)`. However, if I try to reimplement `BezierNode::setPos(..)`, it's never triggered on moving object.

```
void BezierNode::setPos(const QPointF &pos) {
    qDebug() << "setPos " << pos;
    m_point = pos;
    QGraphicsItem::setPos(pos);
}
```

In my case `setPos()` triggers only in constructor (there I call it manually). Yes, it moves in scene properly, I can get its position with `pos()` and use it everywhere instead of m_point, but I want to understand, what happens there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

[QGraphicsItem::setPos()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setPos) is not virtual, so you can't override it. That's why BezierNode::setPos() will never be called.

Comment: So I should place all the hooks in `itemChange()`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually trying to do - why can't you use the return value of the `pos()` function instead of having your own `m_point` member?